# Drupal - Print path to image cache image?

Tags: drupal-theming

I have an image added as a CCK field. In a node tpl file how can I print the url to the image cache image?

I need to add the image cache image as an inline style background image, to a div in my node tpl file.

The Content Template module gives me a few options but not quite what I need. It allows me to print the image cache image as html content, but doenst give me the file path to use as an inline style. It also allows me to print the image file path, but only for the full image not the image cache version.

Content Template does give me the name of the image cache preset, so I can manually write this:
my-site.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/preset-name/file-name-token

However im thinking their must be a cleaner way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have!

```
theme('imagecache', 'name_of_your_preset', $item['filepath']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The key was "imagecache_create_url".

```
<?php
  print imagecache_create_url('imagecache_name', $node->field_name[0]['filepath']);
?>
```